# Angularjs ui bootstrap modal doesn't work without resolve option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a reusable component but I keep getting issue if I don't pass resolve, what is wrong here.. thanks

```
$scope.open = function () {
             var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: '../../App/template/commentsModal.html',
                size: ''
                 ,
                controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,

                 resolve: {
                     items: function () {
                         return 'b';
                     }
                 }


             });
```

But if I remove resolve then I keep getting [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: itemsProvider <- items

What is items is this something internal to angularjs? here is the modal controller:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

})
```

Comment: `items` you must have listed as a dependency in the controller (though the pasted code doesn't seem like showing it), it is nothing but the name of the temporary service (`items`) that you have in the resolve.

Comment: `.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',function($scope,$modalInstance,items)`

Comment: @PSL I intentionally left items out but I am still getting that error. without the resolve

Comment: @m.e.conroy I know if I add it in the controller header then it will give me error but in my case I am not and its still giving DI error.

Comment: Try making controller a string in your `modal.open`.  `controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'`

Comment: Glad to help, I've done that before.  Its not something that pops out right away as an error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to list items as one of your dependencies on the new controller, that is resolve's purpose.

```
$scope.open = function () {
         var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '../../App/template/commentsModal.html',
            size: '',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                 items: function () {
                     return 'b';
                 }
             }
         });
         modalInstance.result.then(function(data) { //make sure you are declaring your promise
              confirm(data);
         });
};
```

You don't have to declare you controller as part of your module, you can simply make an object.

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, *items*) {
    $scope.items = items;

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.items);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

});
```

Essentially, resolve will send items to your defined modal controller, assign it to that local scope, and then return it with the promise, back to your starting controller. You can see how you can take data, pass to the modal to be changed, and return the new result and rebind to your original controller.  Make sure to declare your modal controller outside of your main controller and pass in anything else you need using this method.

Make sure you are declaring $modal in your main controller, and $modalInstance in your modal controller.